# Can't get any data from kinect

Tags: ros, kinect, openni.launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So here's the deal,

Whenever I tried using openni_launch, it worked normally, however, when I tried viewing an image using the kinect's rgb or depth camera, or even recording a simple bagfile with data from the kinect, I was unable to see any picture and rosbag did not record any data, and after a few seconds of running image_view or rosbag record, I got this error:

### --

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'openni_wrapper::OpenNIException'
what():  virtual void openni_wrapper::OpenNIDevice::startImageStream() @ /tmp/buildd/ros-groovy-openni-camera-1.8.8-0precise-20130418-2203/src/openni_device.cpp @ 224 : starting image stream failed. Reason: Xiron OS got an event timeout!
[camera_nodelet_manager-2] process has died [pid 3788, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=camera_nodelet_manager __log:=/home/rosbotics/.ros/log/16b63744-e043-11e2-ac16-080027486aa8/camera_nodelet_manager-2.log].
log file: /home/rosbotics/.ros/log/16b63744-e043-11e2-ac16-080027486aa8/camera_nodelet_manager-2*.log

### --

After searching around and trying various fixes, I figured it might be a problem with openni and started using freenect, howver I encountered the same problems, I could not record any data using bagfiles or see any images from the kinect (using rviz or image_view)

Then someone asked me to use something completely unrelated, freenect-glview, however that too gave me a black screen.

lsusb shows that all 3 parts of the kinect are connected and I've been able to control the kinect's motor through ubuntu so I know that there is at least a connection established between both.

Additional Info:

- I run ROS on Ubuntu using VirtualBox V.4.2.14 and Windows 7 with USB 2 ports
- I am using ubuntu 12.04 and ROS-Groovy (all up to date)
- I've had the exact same errors on my Mac OSX Lion
- When I try using Rviz with the kinect, VirtualBox crashes all together

I would appreciate anyone's help on the matter.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67787/can%27t-get-any-data-from-kinect/) by [Loufis](https://answers.ros.org/users/5297/loufis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2013-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm the person who suggested freenect-glview ... if you can't see images from the camera at all, I'd focus on fixing that in isolation before you try using it with the ROS drivers. I don't know what your exact problem is, but if the logfile referenced in that error message you copied over isn't informative, I'd start asking:

- Does it work under Windows? (I use OSX/Ubuntu, so can't suggest a program to use, but I expect that one exists)
- Have you tried other ways to visualize its output in your linux VM? If freenect-glview doesn't work, does it provide any error messages that you could google?
- Can you use other USB cameras within your virtual machine?
- What about alternatives to VirtualBox?
- You mention Lion - does `brew install libfreenect; glview` work for you? (I had to do `sudo glview` to get rgb alongside depth)

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Loufis](https://answers.ros.org/users/5297/loufis/) on 2013-07-22**:
Thank you for everything, it turns out VirtualBox was causing everything to not work properly for some reason. Now I'm using VMware and everything's running fine. What confused me was that I was getting errors that I found online and that even after trying every fix I could find some would still be there. Next step is getting XYZ coordinates of a moving robot, I'll start looking for tutorials right away (I'm still new to ros). Anyway, thank you for everything and if you have any links for tutorials about this I would appreciate it.